# Let $L$ be the line $y = mx$, where $m \neq 0$. Find an expression for $T(x,y)$, where $T$ is the reflection of $\textbf{R}^{2}$ about $L$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, change-of-basis, projection

In $\textbf{R}^{2}$, let $L$ be the line $y = mx$, where $m \neq 0$. Find an expression for $T(x,y)$, where

(a) $T$ is the reflection of $\textbf{R}^{2}$ about $L$.

(b) $T$ is the projection on $L$ along the line perpendicular to $L$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) Let us consider the basis $\mathcal{B}' = \{(1,m),(-m,1)\}$. Then we must have $T(1,m) = (1,m)$ and $T(-m,1) = (m,-1)$.

Thus the matrix representation of $T$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}'$ is given by
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}'} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the change of basis matrix from $\mathcal{B}'$ to $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is given by
\begin{align*}
Q =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -m\\
m & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\Rightarrow Q^{-1} =
\frac{1}{m^{2}+1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & m\\
-m & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Finally, we have that $[T]_{\mathcal{B}} = Q[T]_{\mathcal{B}'}Q^{-1}$:
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}} =\frac{1}{m^{2}+1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1-m^{2} & 1 + m\\
2m & m^{2}-1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

(b) In this case, the basis is the same: $\mathcal{B}' = \{(1,m),(-m,1)\}$. But $T(1,m) = 
(1,m)$ and $T(-m,1) = 0$. Thus we get that

\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}'} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
from whence we get that $[T]_{\mathcal{B}} = Q[T]_{\mathcal{B}'}Q^{-1}$:
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}} = \frac{1}{m^{2}+1}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & m\\
m & m^{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Is my approach to solve this problem correct? Could someone propose another way to solve it?

Comment: Your approach is fine. There are other approaches but more or less they are very similar. For example to get the matrix for $T$ one just needs to know where $\mathbf{e}_1$  and $\mathbf{e}_2$ will map to and reflection about the given line can be interpreted in terms of rotation.